# Java : Fuzzy search on List of Phrases

Tags: java, search, collections

I have Two List of Strings `Patterns` and `Queries` as below and perform fuzzy search without using any libraries.

```
   P = {"i would have", "they love", "i analyzed", "made decision"};
   queries = {"since this morning i have analyzed all the data from the company and made my decision",
            "they love the idea"};

A fuzzy search is that there can be at max extra one word in the phrase.
Fuzzy search all the phrases in the query string and the expected output search phrases
are -> [["i have analyzed", "made my decision"], ["they love"]]
```

I was able to comeup with bruteforce solution and it works for the above use case

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fuzzy_search(String[] P, String[] queries) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String query : queries){
        ArrayList<String> queryTokens = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(query.split(" ")));
        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String pattern : P){
            String[] patternTokens = pattern.split(" ");
            ArrayList<Integer> ii = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String patternToken : patternTokens){
                    int i = queryTokens.indexOf(patternToken);
                    if(i >=0)
                        ii.add(i);
                    else {
                        ii.clear();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            if(!ii.isEmpty()){
                int n = ii.get(ii.size()-1) - ii.get(0);
                if(n==ii.size() || n == ii.size()-1){
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int kk = ii.get(0); kk< ii.get(ii.size()-1)+1; kk++) {
                        sb.append(queryTokens.get(kk));
                        if (kk != ii.get(ii.size() - 1))
                            sb.append(" ");
                    }
                    matches.add(sb.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        result.add(matches);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But its not working for the complex examples like below. can someone please help me with the efficient solution which would work for the complex scenario like below

```
{
  "queries": [
    "close box son add bad strong afford down bad middle",
    "business become for department chap offer business become for chap tell afford aware bad name business become for committee chap normal around egg expect learn prepare balance goodbye lot forget welcome"
  ],
  "phrases": [
    "balance goodbye lot forget",
    "health contact ever big",
    "business become for chap",
    "approach field",
    "else after blow inform",
    "around egg expect learn",
    "add bad",
    "increase accept",
    "close box",
    "afford bad"
  ],
  "solution": [
    [
      "close box",
      "add bad",
      "afford down bad"
    ],
    [
      "business become for department chap",
      "business become for chap",
      "afford aware bad",
      "business become for committee chap",
      "around egg expect learn",
      "balance goodbye lot forget"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the output/solution a bit more - why are there two lists of words and what is supposed to be in each? 
Part of my confusion is: In your first example, it looked like the first list was the fuzzy results with the extra word included, and the second list were all the exact matches. In your second example, that was swapped.

Comment: Both the examples have 2 phrases in the Queries so the search results should have one list per each query phrase. In simple terms query phrases should be matched with pattern phrases with at most one extra word can present in query phrase.